# How do I change the verbiage for "sign up fee" in Woocommerce Subscriptions?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-subscriptions

I used another code to hide the price string under the product title, however, when you select the variations, the price string appears at the bottom above the add to cart button. I would like to change the words "sign up fee" to "deposit" and also invert the string to say "$100 deposit and $67.50/month".

I have tried other codes but they only work for the price string that appears under the product title, which I have hidden.

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  
'invert_subscription_signup_fee_and_monthly_fee_text', 10, 3 );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  
'invert_subscription_signup_fee_and_monthly_fee_text', 10, 3 );
function invert_subscription_signup_fee_and_monthly_fee_text( 
$translated, $text, $domain  ) {
if( $text === '%1$s and a %2$s sign-up fee' && $domain === 
'woocommerce-subscriptions' ){
    $translated = __( '%2$s sign-up fee and a %1$s', $domain );
}
return $translated;
}
```

I expect the price string that appears after the client has chosen the variation to read "$100 deposit and 67.50/month".

Comment: Are you using any plugin?

Comment: Yes, I am using Woocommerce Subscriptions.